# Trouble calculating conditional expectation

Tags: statistics, conditional-expectation

I am having trouble with the following problem regarding conditional expectation. Consider the random variables $X,Y$ and $Z$ with mean and dispersion matrix

$$\mu=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix},\ \Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}1 & \rho & \rho \\ \rho & 1 & \rho\\ \rho & \rho & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Furthermore, consider the random variables $U=X+Y+Z$ and $V=2X-Y-Z$.

I am now asked to calculate $\text{E}\left(\begin{bmatrix}X\\ Y\end{bmatrix}\large{|}Z=z\right)$ and from my lecture notes I am told that computing this is done in the following way:

$$\text{E}(X_1|X_2=x_2)\mu_1+\Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}(x_2-\mu_2)$$

where the normally distributed random variable $X$ has been partitioned into the following:

$$X=\begin{bmatrix}X_1\\X_2\end{bmatrix},\ \mu=\begin{bmatrix}\mu_1\\\mu_2\end{bmatrix},\ \Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12}\\ \Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22}\end{bmatrix}$$

I am completely confused with how I am supposed to use this with the formula given above. Can someone help me figure out how to determine what $\Sigma_{12}$ and $\Sigma_{22}$ is? I can't connect this to the given setting introduced in the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there an unstated but crucial assumption that $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are jointly gaussian?

Comment: The random variable $X$ is normally distributed. My bad, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: What about $Y$ and $Z$ ?

Comment: They are also normally distributed.

Comment: What do $U$ and $V$ have to do with the problem statement?

Comment: They have nothing to do with this specific problem, but there were other problems where they were used. I just decided to write everything given in the problem so there wasn't any lack of information.